# Ubuntu 16.04 no loading!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I've installed alongside my Windows10 following the steps of [How To Install Ubuntu Linux Alongside Windows 10 (UEFI)](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html).

After installation I am asked to reboot... During reboot they wanted me to *remove* the USB (Mounted with OS) and press ENTER... I did it. Then it automatically booted into windows.

Still now while powering on my laptop there are no boot options displayed for loading Ubuntu or Windows. It automatically boots Windows 10.

Can somebody help me to solve this problem? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 10 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Comment: Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+restart and load Ubuntu from the drive. Weird. But happened to me as well.